# Boundedness of continuous summable function

Tags: fourier-analysis, lp-spaces

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{C}$ be a continuous function.
If we suppose that $f$ is a $L^1(\mathbb{R;C})$ function too, then can we conclude that $f$ is bounded?

**ADD**: I asked the preceding question to give an answer for the following problem.

If $f$ and its Fourier Transform are $L^1(\mathbb{R;C})$ functions, then inversion theorem holds almost everywhere. In addition, if $f$ is *countinuous* and *bounded*, inversion theorem holds on the whole real line. Does inversion take place when $f$ is just continuous and not bounded?

Comment: By "limited" you mean "bounded"? Then the answer is no. Consider a sequence of ever narrower and ever higher peaks marching to infinity. If the peaks become narrower fast enough, you get something integrable.

Comment: I switched to the appropriate term "bounded" and added more content.

Comment: If the Fourier transform of $f$ is in $L^1$ (and $f$ too, of course), then $f$ is almost everywhere identical to the reflection of the Fourier transform of $\hat{f}$, which is a continuous and bounded function. If $f$ is continuous, the equality is not only almost everywhere but everywhere, since if two continuous functions are distinct, they differ on a nonempty open set, and that has positive measure.

Comment: So, if $f \in L^1 \land \hat{f}\in L^1$, then $f$ has a continuous representative, and the Fourier inversion gives an equality everywhere for that continuous representative. Then that continuous representative of $f$ is necessarily bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "bounded" can be dropped from the sentence

> In addition, if $f$ is continuous and bounded, inversion theorem holds on the whole real line.

Indeed, we are assuming that the Fourier transform of $f$ is integrable. This implies $f$ is in $L^\infty$ and has a continuous representative (as D.F. commented). Assuming "$f$ is continuous" means that we look at this continuous representative for $f$. It is bounded, with $\sup|f| = \|f\|_{L^\infty}$. Indeed, if $|f(a)|>\|f\|_{L^\infty}$, then by continuity there is a neighborhood of $a$ in which $|f |>\|f\|_{L^\infty}$. This contradicts the definition of $\|f\|_{L^\infty}$.

Summary:

> If an element of $L^\infty$ has a continuous representative, that representative is bounded.